# complexity theory: polynomial hierarchy for function problems / TSP with output

Tags: complexity-theory, traveling-salesman, polynomial-time-hierarchy

I'm searching for equivalent problem classes from the polynomial hierarchy to function problems. I have this problem similar to traveling salesperson, which imo lies in the second order of polynomial hierarchy. However the existence of an answer can always be answered with yes due to the structure of the problem. Therefore the questions is not if there is an answer or not, but the actual path, like for function problems. Is there a a similar construct for function problems or do I just go with FNP^NP or NP^NP?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that "imo [the problem] lies in the second order of polynomial hierarchy"? Also, what is this problem?